# Extract Data Frrom Elastic Index, Process And Return

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, microservices

I have an Index in Elastic with about 40M records.
I need to to send all the data to a service I have, running on a docker,
and then return the processed data to a new index.

How Can I do that?

I tried using python script for that purpose, but it failed to the huge amount of records inside the index.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use batching. Since you are only fetching data, you can use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html).
It is similar to how cursors work in other databases.

Comment: Hi and thx for your answer. The thing is I query about 200M records,and before I send them I need to store them in a file. I use the scan method but it takes about 15 min for 10M records. do you know a faster way?

Comment: I am not sure about scan, but as far as I know scroll is the recommended approach for handling lots of documents. You can even break down into chunks using slice scrolling. By the way, 15 mins to process 10M records does not sound that bad.